# How can I ensure there is never more than one instance of form open at any time in vb 6?

Tags: vb6

I am using a from as below using VB 6. Now, for every single click of the button that is order to load the form, it creates a new instance of the form. How can I ensure there is never more than one instance of form open at any time?

```
  Dim objForm As frmSelectStyle
  Set objForm = New frmSelectStyle

 With objForm
   .aaInitialize SelectStyleDlg:=SelectStyleDlg
   .Show vbModeless
 End With
```

Please help me. Thank you.

Comment: `Set objForm = New frmSelectStyle` tells it to create a new one.

Comment: Hi @catcat , Yes. I want to know another way to load the form object instead of using this. Do you have any idea?

Comment: `obfform.show` is all you need to do. Put the other lines outside your procedure.

Comment: I used objForm.show  ,  but it caused the Error -91  "Object variable or with block variable not set" .

Comment: Based on your example, you should use `frmSelectStyle.show`

Comment: Hi @BillHileman , Thank you for your answer. It works !!!

Answer (score 1):

This is how I was able to solve this problem, with the help of @Bill Hileman.

```
With frmSelectStyle
  .aaInitialize SelectStyleDlg:=SelectStyleDlg
  .Show vbModeless
End With
```

This worked nicely.